# Maya Python - Change Button Icon Based On Active Command

Tags: python, button, icons, menuitem, maya

Working with maya 16

I do have an `iconTextButton` setup, with a `popupMenu` containing several `menuItem`, where each `menuItem` comes with an icon. I want the parent, the  `iconTextButton`, to display the `menuItem` icon based on which `menuItem` is currently active.

This is my current setup:

```
cmds.iconTextButton( style='iconAndTextHorizontal', image1='MainButton.png', h=40,w=100, bgc=[0.35, 0.35, 0.35], label='Open Submenu Pallet')

def someImportantFunction (*args):
    somethingImportant

cmds.popupMenu(b=1)
cmds.menuItem(label='do Something', command=someImportantFunction, image1='subMenuIconToChangeTo.png')
```

I`m still pretty new to scripting and logic in general, just cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just edit the original button to change it's appearance when you fire off the menu commands:

```
window = cmds.window(title='example')
layout = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
ict = cmds.iconTextButton( style='iconAndTextHorizontal', image1='MainButton.png', h=40,w=100, bgc=[0.35, 0.35, 0.35], label='Open Submenu Pallet')
popup = cmds.popupMenu(b=1)

def something(*_):
    print "something" # real work goes here
    cmds.iconTextButton(ict, e=True, label = 'something')

def something_else(*_):
    print "something else"
    cmds.iconTextButton(ict, e=True, label = 'something else')

cmds.menuItem(label='something', image1='somethingIcon', c= something)
cmds.menuItem(label='something else', image1='otherIcon', c=something_else)
cmds.setParent("..")
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

The key is to make sure you hang on to a reference to the widgets you create so you can edit or query them using the `e=True` or `q=True` flags for your gui items.

Comment: One more thing if you dont mind. now that the `iconTextbutton` will show the selected `menuItem`, how would i have to set it up so the `iconTextButton` changes its default command, based on the currently selected `menuItem`. i imagine its just a small step from what i have now, didnt find any reference tho.